# passing string to the Uri.parse() in download

Tags: java, android

I get url string with parsing the json . And when i pass this string to `Uri.parse()` method for getting file with download manager it doesn't work .I check the downloadUrl befor sending to Uri.parse() and it hava a correct value,

This is my code :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.txtTitle.setText(questionha.get(position).getQuestionTitle());
    holder.txtDesc.setText(questionha.get(position).getQuestionDesc());
    holder.txtCntDown.setText(questionha.get(position).getQuestionDownCnt());
    holder.txtAuthorName.setText(questionha.get(position).getQuestionAuthorName());
    Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(questionha.get(position).getQuestionAuthorPic()).into(holder.imgAuthorPic);
    holder.txtDate.setText(questionha.get(position).getQuestionDate());
    holder.btnDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //===========================================================================
            JsonObjectRequest volleyRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(questionha.get(position).getQuestionDownLink(), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    if (response != null || response.length() > 0) {
                        try {
                          ===>  String downloadUrl = response.getString("link");

                            DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService (Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(downloadUrl));
                            request.setTitle(questionha.get(position).getQuestionTitle())
                                    .setDescription("در حال دانلود")
                                    .setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, "", "salam");
                            long enqueueId = downloadManager.enqueue(request);

                            Log.i("DonwloadUrl",response.getString("link"));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(volleyRequest);

            //==============================================================================
            //Toast.makeText(context, DownloadUrl, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });

}
```

And when i pass the string of the url statically it is worked !. 
And this is my DownloadUrl value :

[Screenshot link](http://s6.picofile.com/file/8252082334/response.JPG)

Thanks

Comment: can you give us your raw String and what you have  
retrieve from json?

Comment: I added screenshot link pooyan

Comment: so what is wrong? dose it get exception?

Comment: no i dont hava exception but download manager doesn't work with that and when add this value statically in Uri.parse() it worked !!!. my mean is like that Uri.parse("value of downloadurl ")

Comment: so i think that your "downloadUrl " is different from what you expect. can you log it and its length and compare it and its length with correct string?

Comment: wow , it add the www to first of the url and it get 404 error , what can i do with that ?

Comment: i dont think that "www" has been added by code! i think there is problem in your main json data that you will parse it.